# Get button click from reusable cell in collection view (xib file)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have created reusable cell with include a button in a XIB for a collection.

I can change the text of labels and buttons in the collection view but i can't get on click event.

I have tried below options:

a.   This in UICollectionViewCell :  **Not working**

```
class cellVC: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var sampleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonClicked: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonTest(_ sender: Any) {
        print("dsfsdf   111111")
    }
}
```

b. I have also tried : **Not working**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell : cellVC = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellVC", for: indexPath) as! cellVC
    cell.sampleLabel. = "sample text"
    cell.buttonClicked.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.buttonClicked.addTarget(self, action: #selector(masterAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.buttonClicked.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    return cell
}


func masterAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print ("button click")
}
```

As both solutions are not working, how do i achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: is your button click fired ?

Comment: What does `masterAction(sender:)`  look like?

Comment: @Moshe i have edited the code

Comment: What's actually happening? Is your code crashing, or just not printing out what you expect?

Comment: @Moshe nothing happens, the code those not crash. I have used break points and masterActions function is not called on click

Comment: Are you registering your XIB cell with `register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` ?

Comment: @DonMag yes i am in viewDidLoad() in the view controller

Comment: @John - OK... if you are not even getting output from `print("dsfsdf   111111")` (in your "a." code), then you don't have your button connected to the IBAction correctly. You need to fix that before trying any other solution. Check the connection on your button - if one is there, delete it and then re-connect it, making sure it's TouchUpInside and connected to your `@IBAction func buttonTest(_ sender: Any)`

Comment: Updated my answer to reference a complete Xcode project. Check it out and see if that helps at all.

Comment: My guess: the tableView gesture recognizer catches the tap cancelling the UIControl touch event. Translated: the didSelectRow at index cancels your button touch up inside. You can try to put the selection style of the cell to none. this should do the trick. Let me know.

Comment: Here is another runnable example: https://github.com/DonMag/CollViewXIBCells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happen when the button is linked to the File's Owner instead of your cell.

Right click on the button in IB and check if the referencing outlet is correct, this should be your cell and not the File's Owner like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Did you try disabling userInteraction for your cell's content view?  `self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`
It is possible that the button's touchUpInside event is sent to the tableview's `didSelectRowAt` instead?

Comment: @Thomas I had the same issue. I searched the whole web for a solution to this issue, finally it was your comment that solved the issue.

Comment: Hi @Thomas What if button is in uiview?? I have a form type UI with Submit button in it. I have to reuse the form xib again in another VC, but now the buttons title is "OK" and it has to perform different action. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

#### Places To Check

There are several potential points of failure here, because what you're doing *seems* to look right. I have a sample Xcode project which has this working. (See it on [GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/stackoverflow-samples/tree/master/44907944-CollectionViewCellWithButton).)

You can double check these things, to make sure everything is set up correctly:

- Your collection view's data source and delegate are wired up
- Your button and sample label have their outlet's connected correctly
- Your storyboard has the appropriate class and identifier set up
- Your selector is named correctly

It seems, based on what you've posted here that all of the above conditions are true, so let's talk a little more about what you're trying to do and see how all the pieces fit.

#### Why these Things Seem Ok

- If the data source and delegate were incorrectly set up, you wouldn't see your cells.
- If your outlets were incorrectly wired, you'd end up with crashes, because `IBOutlets` are force-unwrapped by default. (And that's how your posted code works.)
- Your storyboard seems to be set up correctly because, again, your cells wouldn't appear without the right set up.
- An incorrectly named selector wouldn't even compile.

#### Implications of Cells and Recycling

In general, this is a tricky problem to solve, because of the way `UICollectionView` is designed. (The same applies to `UITableView`.)

Your button is inside of a re-usable collection view cell, which means that you not only have to handle taps, but you need to know which index path in your data set the button is currently referring to.

Further, views that are placed inside an instance of `UICollectionViewCell` are actually inside the collection view cell's `contentView`, which makes it just a little more work to handle.

Finally, if your cells scroll on and offscreen, then you may end up attaching the action to your button multiple times as the cell is recycled. So, you need to account for that as well.

#### An Implementation Example

Let's work with a very simple custom cell, that has a single button in it:
[image: An image of a collection view cell with a single centered button.]

The code for the button looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var updateButton: UIButton!
}
```

Really simple. Notice the `IBOutlet`. That needs to be wired up in interface builder as well.

[image: An image of the Xcode inspector, showing the button wired up to its outlet]

The last thing we need to do is set up the cell's reuse identifier so that we can access it in code. With the cell selected in Interface Builder, add an identifier to the cell:

[image: A screenshot of Xcode inspector, showing a collection view cell's identifier]

Ok, that's all you need to do with the cell. We're ready to implement the view controller. In the view controller, we're going to set up a few things:

1. A label to show that our button inside the cell was tapped
2. An outlet for our collection view, so we can get the index path of the cell that contains the button. (If you're using a `UICollectionViewController` instead of a`UIViewController`, this won't be necessary.)
3. Some code to show our custom cell.
4. Some code to handle the button tap.

Let's start with the `IBOutlets`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lastTappedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

We need to wire those up in Interface builder. While you're at it, *also* connect the collection view's data source and delegate to be the "File's Owner" if they aren't connected already. (Again, if you're using a `UICollectionViewController` instead of a`UIViewController`, this won't be necessary.)

Next, let's implement some code to show our custom cell, using `UICollectionViewDataSource`. We need to show at least one section and at least one cell:

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 36
}
```

When we dequeue the cell, we want to force downcast our dequeued cell to the custom cell class we defined earlier. Then we can access the update button to add an action to it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "com.mosheberman.samples.cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    cell.updateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateLabel(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Now we need to implement the method for accessing the index path of the cell:

```
// MARK: - Updating the Label

@objc func updateLabel(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    print("\(sender) tapped. Update label called.")

    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else
    {
        print("Sender isn't a button. Returning.")
        return
    }

    guard let contentView = button.superview else
    {
        print("Button isn't inside a contentView. Returning.")
        return
    }

    guard let cell = contentView.superview as? UICollectionViewCell else
    {
        print("View's superview isn't a UICollectionViewCell instance. Returning.")
        return
    }

    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else
    {
        print("Our collection view isn't wired up. Returning.")
        return
    }

    guard let indexPathForCell = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else
    {
        print("The cell doesn't correspond to an index path. Maybe it's not a child of this collection view?")
        return
    }

    self.lastTappedLabel.text = "Tapped button at \(indexPathForCell.item), \(indexPathForCell.section)"
}
```

This method handles all of the checks you need to handle the tap and determine which item was actually tapped.

1. We need to ensure the `sender` is actually a `UIButton` instance. Not critical, but if we don't at least ensure it's a `UIView`, we won't be able to get the `superview`.
2. Once we have that, ensure the button is inside a `superview`, which we assume to be the `contentView`.
3. Check for the superview of the content view, and we'll have the cell itself.
4. At this point we can ask the collection view (which we have a reference to, because of the outlet set up above) for the index path to the cell.
5. Once we have an index path, we can update our label or do something with the data backing the cell.

#### Notes

- While testing this I see that you may not actually need to remove the target-action anymore - UIKit seems to do the right thing now and only calls your method once.
- The code we wrote here is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/stackoverflow-samples/tree/master/44907944-CollectionViewCellWithButton).

**Edit:**

@DonMag pointed out that you're using a nib instead of a storyboard, which I overlooked initially. So, here's the process for getting it all set up with nibs:

1. We can use the same cell class as above, but we need to add a separate nib for it, because the view controller nib doesn't support cell prototypes.
2. We need to register the nib separately, for the same reason. Including a cell prototype in the storyboard does this automatically. When working with nibs, you don't get this for free.
3. We need to set up the view controller in the nib.
4. Almost all of the other code can be moved over from the storyboard version.

Let's start by making a new nib for the `CustomCollectionViewCell`. Using the "Empty" template, make a new nib called "CustomCollectionViewCell.xib." The name doesn't have to match the class, but it's going to be used later on, so to follow convention, let's call it that.

In the new nib, drag out a collection view cell from the palette on the bottom right, and then add the label to it. Set the custom class to `CustomViewControllerCell` (or whatever yours is called) and connect the label to the outlet.

Next, let's make a new View Controller. We probably can re-use the initial one, but so that we don't register two cells for the same identifier, let's stick to a new `UIViewController` subclass. To get the nib, check "Also create XIB file."

Inside the new nib-based view controller, we want the same outlets as we had before. We also want the same UICollectionViewDataSource implementation. There's one thing that's different here: we need to register the cell.

To do so, let's add a method called `registerCollectionViewCell()` which we'll call from `viewDidLoad`. Here's what it looks like:

```
// MARK: - Setting Up The Collection View Cell

func registerCollectionViewCell()
{
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else
    {
        print("We don't have a reference to the collection view.")
        return
    }

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main) 

    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "com.mosheberman.samples.cell")
}
```

Our `viewDidLoad()` method looks like this now:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.registerCollectionViewCell()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Inside the nib, lay out the label and collection view as we did before. Wire up the outlets and the collection view data source, and delegate, and we should be done!

A couple of other things:

- In my demo project, I needed to also present the nib-based version of the view controller. I did that in the app delegate by replacing whatever the app's main storyboard loaded in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`
- Your storyboard nib should have the File's Owner left to the default value of `NSObject`. The cell should have a custom class matching whatever class you want to load.

Comment: While detailed, your code / commentary doesn't address the fact the OP is loading his cell from a XIB. In addition, I'd highly recommend using a closure to "call back" to the view controller on button tap, as "Alexey" shows in his answer.

Comment: @DonMag I'm not sure that Storyboards are different from nibs in this case - I'm going to test that. Can you tell me why a callback is better here? If anything, wouldn't it make it more difficult to access the indexPath of the cell, given that the logic moves from the view controller, which can access the collection view, to the cell, which is a display class?

Comment: Ah, I see the difference between the storyboard and nib here. You can't wire up the cell as easily here. Makes sense.

Comment: Also, it looks like I missed the point with the callback. I still think it's a matter of opinion, but I appreciate that approach now.

Comment: indexPath of the cell exists in the closure. Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/bdbc20d3c3ae51181a64e2838b679eae When that code is run (assuming the cell is properly connected to the xib), the print output is (for example): `Button tapped in cell: [0, 4]`

Comment: @DonMag Updated to include nib-based version.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
 cell.buttonClicked.addTarget(self, action: #selector(masterAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

write

```
 cell.buttonClicked.addTarget(self, action: #selector(masterAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: masterAction function is not called

Answer (score 1):

You can go with:

```js
    class cellVC: UICollectionViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var sampleLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var buttonClicked: UIButton!

        var buttonTapAction: ((cellVC) -> ())?

        @IBAction func buttonTest(_ sender: Any) {
            buttonTapAction?(self)
        }
    }
    
    //////////
    
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell : cellVC = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellVC", for: indexPath) as! cellVC
    cell.sampleLabel. = "sample text"
    cell.buttonClicked.tag = indexPath.row
  
    cell.buttonTapAction = { cell in 
    
    //Tap handling logic
    
    }

    cell.buttonClicked.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hey there, I have this error: `Cannot call value of non-function type '((cellVC) -> ())?'`

Comment: @SAt Maybe there is something missing, need more information.

Comment: it could be simple view hierarchy problem, there could be a view over the button which is not allowing you get the click. Debug the view

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Thomas If anyone wants the solution, the answer up top has been updated in swift :

```
self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```