# Button inside CollectionView not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I have a button in a custom cell of a collectionview. The collectionview is on a scrollview. For some reason, I am not able to click on the button. I've checked that all my elements have User Interaction enabled.

Here is my layout of the collection (I've hidden some sensitive data)
[image]

Here is my custom collection view cell:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var connectButton: UIButton!

    var onConnectTap: (MyCollectionViewCell) -> Void)?
    @IBAction func connectButton(_ sender: Any) {
        onConnectTap?(self)
    }

    func populate(_ user: User) {
        nameLabel.text = user.name
     }
}
```

I have a xib file where a Touch Up Inside event of a button has been hooked up to the connectButton IBAction.

And in my ViewController:

```
MyCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Here's my collection view function in my ViewController:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        let user = users.values[indexPath.row]
        cell.populate(user)

        cell.onConnectTap = { (cell) in
            //do something
        }

        return cell

}
```

Nothing happens when I click on the button. Am I missing something here? Is the scroll view interfering? Do I need to specifiy a addTarget? Or something else?

Comment: Is `connectButton` not called either? Have you hooked it up correctly in the interface builder?

Comment: It's not called, and yes I've double checked that it's hooked up correctly in IB.

Comment: create delegate method of button

Comment: You should try to set your collection view and its parent scroll view clipsToBounds attribute to `true`. Since your collection view is in a scroll view, the sizing of the scroll view can be challenging and maybe you can see the cell but the parent views don't have the right sizes, messing up the response chain.

Comment: @DirtyHenry both alreayd have Clip To Bounds set to true in IB.

Comment: @Prabhu and have you checked that the frame/content sizes of both parents views were OK?

Comment: Yes they seem to be fine

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After searching the entire web pretty much, I finally found the solution that was in the comment of this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908916/406322

I needed to add this in MyCollectionViewCell:

```
self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

I think the cell selection was hijacking the touch event.

Comment: great worked for me, after trying whole day
            cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
and 
 public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
    {
     
        print(URL)
        return true
    }

Comment: Wow, that's super obscure. Great find!

Comment: If this solution worked for you, it's probably because in *MyCollectionViewCell* you are not properly adding your button as a subview (or subview of a subview) of `contentView`; you might be adding your button to the `view` instead. So the solution — instead of disabling interactions on `contentView`, you should be adding button to the `contentView` instead of the `view`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue and found the best solution after spending much time.

```
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

But its the perfect solution, and adds only one line in the cell for item method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

     cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
     return cell
}
```

Comment: please check which view or button you want to click make sure userinteraction is enabled or not @Chandni

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the structure of the XIB file. I lost time dealing with this issue (where the button in the XIB did not seem to respond), as the structure had a second embedded cell, rather than just one (AboutCell in my case).

[image]